# UNIX: running processes in a loop with fork() and dup2() ends loop early

Tags: c, unix

I am beginning to code a shell in UNIX to practice with API calls such as fork() dup2(), read(), and wait(). Currently, my shell opens and runs fine. When I type a command to run, such as ls -a, it parses this command properly, and executes it. The problem is, the main loop terminates early, exiting the shell after a single command. I need the loop to continue to run until 'exit' is read from stdin. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
static const char prompt[] = "myshell> ";
static const char sep[] = " \t\n\r";
int main()
{
    int ac; // arg count
    char *av[10]; //argument vector
    int tty = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR); // open tty for read/write
    int pid; // process id
    int status; // child process exit status
    int w;
    void (*istat)(int), (*qstat)(int);

    if (tty == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open /dev/tty\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        char *arg, line[256]; // buffer to hold line of input
        int i;
        // prompt and read
        write(tty, prompt, sizeof(prompt) - 1);
        i = read(tty, line, sizeof(line));
        if (i <= 0)
            break;
        line[i] = '\0';
        // tokenize the line into av[]
        ac = 0;
        for (arg = strtok(line, sep); arg && ac < 10; arg = strtok(NULL, sep))
            av[ac++] = arg;

        if (ac > 0 && strcmp(av[0], "exit") == 0)
            break;

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            // this is the forked child process that is a copy of the running program
            dup2(tty, 0); // stdin from tty
            dup2(tty, 1); // stdout to tty
            dup2(tty, 2); // stderr to tty
            close(tty);
            // last argument must be NULL for execvp()
            av[ac] = NULL;
            // execute program av[0] with arguments av[0]... replacing this program
            execvp(av[0], av);
            fprintf(stderr, "can't execute %s\n", av[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(tty);
        // disable interrupt (^C and kill -TERM) and kill -QUIT
        istat = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        qstat = signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
        // wait until forked child process terminated, get its exit status
        while ((w = wait(&status)) != pid && w != -1)
            continue;
        if (w == -1)
            status = -1;

    }

    // restore interrupt and quit signals
    signal(SIGINT, istat);
    signal(SIGQUIT, qstat);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I tried moving these lines right above exit success (so they're outside of the loop and inside main)

```
    close(tty);
    // disable interrupt (^C and kill -TERM) and kill -QUIT
    istat = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    qstat = signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    // wait until forked child process terminated, get its exit status
    while ((w = wait(&status)) != pid && w != -1)
        continue;
    if (w == -1)
        status = -1;

}

// restore interrupt and quit signals
    signal(SIGINT, istat);
    signal(SIGQUIT, qstat);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

What this did is loop the shell properly, but printed the prompt over top the last line of the output from the executed command, because the program wasn't waiting for the child process to end before printing the prompt and waiting for input. I tried moving some of the lines around, but every time it just ends up terminating the shell after one command is executed

Comment: It's not a compilation error, it is an error in functionality. The main while loop terminates after a process executes. It should continue going, as a normal shell would until the exit command is run

Comment: ... and check the returnvalue+errno from execxxx() And: how about EPIPE/SIGPIPE

Comment: The first line in the parent process after the fork is `close(tty)`, you cannot read anymore and you don't reopen the tty. Either you reopen the tty or you don't close it in the parent part after the `fork`

Comment: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not an `int`

Comment: when outputting an error message, that resulted from a C library function, like `open()`, always output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()`  is made for this purpose.

Comment: when calling a function like: `read()` and the returned value is <0, should output a error message to `stderr`

Comment: the function: `fork()` has three kinds of return values: <0 :means an error occurred  ==0 :means in child process  >0 :means in parent process  The code needs to check for (and handle) all three conditions

Comment: regarding: `// last argument must be NULL for execvp()
            av[ac] = NULL;`   This should have been done when 'tokenizing' the user input.  As it is, if there are 10 or more tokens, then this will overflow the array upper bounds, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `close(tty);
        // disable interrupt (^C and kill -TERM) and kill -QUIT
        istat = signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        qstat = signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);`  why the fiddling with the signals?  why would the parent want to close the tty?

Comment: suggest replacing: `while ((w = wait(&status)) != pid && w != -1)
        continue;
    if (w == -1)
        status = -1;` with: `waitpid( pid, NULL, 0 );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to call `close(tty)` within your main loop. Doing so causes your next `read(tty,...` to fail, exiting the shell.

Additionally, if you really want to disable SIGQUIT/SIGQUIT, you should symmetrically restore them within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

the following posted code:

1. skips the handling of the signals, you may want to add that back in.
2. cleanly compiles
3. properly checks for and documents any errors
4. performs the desired functionality, except for the disabling of certain signals
5. continues to execute the loop until the user enters 'exit'

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// added next statement for 'wait()' and 'waitpid()'
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char prompt[] = "myshell> ";
static const char sep[] = " \t\n\r";


int main( void )
{
    int ac; // arg count
    char *av[10]; //argument vector

    pid_t pid; // process id
    int status; // child process exit status


    int tty = open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR); // open tty for read/write
    if (tty == -1)
    {
        perror( "open for /dev/tty failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        char *arg;
        char line[256]; // buffer to hold line of input

        // prompt and read
        write(tty, prompt, sizeof(prompt) - 1);
        ssize_t i = read(tty, line, sizeof(line));

        if (i == 0)
            break;

        if (i < 0)
        {
            perror( "read failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        line[i] = '\0';

        // tokenize the line into av[]
        ac = 0;
        for (arg = strtok(line, sep); arg && ac < 10; arg = strtok(NULL, sep))
            av[ac++] = arg;

        // last argument must be NULL for execvp()
        av[ac] = NULL

        if (ac > 0 && strcmp( av[0], "exit" ) == 0)
            break;

        pid = fork();
        switch( pid )
        {
        case -1:
            perror( "fork failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;

        case 0:  // child process
            // this is the forked child process that is a copy of the running program
            dup2(tty, 0); // stdin from tty
            dup2(tty, 1); // stdout to tty
            dup2(tty, 2); // stderr to tty
            close(tty);
            ;

            // execute program av[0] with arguments av[0]... replacing this program
            execvp(av[0], av);
            perror( "execvp failed" );
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

        default: // parent process
            // wait until forked child process terminated, get its exit status
            waitpid( pid, &status, 0 );
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```